# How to do competing risks regression after IPW?

Tags: r, weights, competing-risks, inverse-problem

There are 4 types of treatment in my data. To balance the covariables of different treatment groups, I have used *twang::mnps* function to perform inverse probability weighting and successfully got the weights. ASMDs shows that the covariables between these four groups are balanced well with weights. But I cannot find a method to perform multivariable competing risks regression in my data after IPW. I only find that *cmprsk::crr* function can be used to perform competing risks regression for multivariables. But there is no argument for weight in the *crr* function. So, how to perform weighted multivariable competing risks regression after IPW?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the cmprskcoxmsm package
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cmprskcoxmsm/cmprskcoxmsm.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to estimate weighted cumulative incidence functions from competing risks data, you can use the `adjustedcif()` function from the `adjustedCurves` package. Small example here:

````
library(adjustedCurves)
library(survival)

set.seed(42)

# simulate some example data
sim_dat <- sim_confounded_crisk(n=500, max_t=1.2)
sim_dat$group <- as.factor(sim_dat$group)

# using direct adjustment with asymptotic confidence intervals for cause 1
# NOTE: if you already have the weights, simply pass those to the
#       'treatment_model' argument
adjcif <- adjustedcif(data=sim_dat,
                      variable="group",
                      ev_time="time",
                      event="event",
                      cause=1,
                      method="iptw_pseudo",
                      treatment_model=group ~ x2 + x4 + x5 + x6,
                      conf_int=TRUE,
                      bootstrap=FALSE)
plot(adjcif)
```
````